# Split data into categories in the same row in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, analytics

I have a table that contains multiple columns with their named having either the suffix `_EXPECTED` or `_ACTUAL`. For example, I'm looking at my sold items from my `SoldItems` Table and I have the following columns: `APPLES_EXPECTED`, `BANANAS_EXPECTED`, `KIWIS_EXPECTED`, `APPLES_ACTUAL`, `BANANAS_ACTUAL`, `KIWIS_ACTUAL` (The Identifier of the table is the date, so we have results per date). I want to show that data in a table form, something like this (for a selected date in filters:

```
+------------+----------+--------+
| Sold items | Expected | Actual |
+------------+----------+--------+
| Apples     |       10 |     15 |
| Bananas    |        8 |      5 |
| Kiwis      |        2 |      1 |
+------------+----------+--------+
```

How can I manage something like this in Power BI ? I tried playing with the matrix/table visualization, however, I can't figure out a way to merge all the expected and actual columns together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the easiest option for you would be to mould the data a bit differently using Power query. You can UNPIVOT your data so that all the expected and actual values become rows instead of columns. For example take the following sample:

```
Date       Apples_Expected Apples_Actual
1/1/2019           1             2
```

Once you unpivot this it will become:

```
Date         Fruit        Count
1/1/2019 Apples_Expected    1
1/1/2019 Apples_Actual      2
```

Once you unpivot, it should be fairly straightforward to get the view you are looking for. The following link should walk you through the steps to unpivot:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok great, I will check for pivoting my data, thanks ! I thought of doing this, but I was scared it would be more difficult to implement since my data is filtered, but I think it's the only solution !